# Operating over a pointer with ranges

Tags: c++, range-v3

The C++ codebase I'm working on calls a C API that returns both a pointer to a list of structs and the length of the list.  What would be the idiomatic means of processing this list with ranges?  Is there an existing adapter or is creating a custom `range_facade` type the best way of handling this?

Comment: Please post some code to make your question a bit more clear.

Comment: `view::counted` ?

Comment: `ranges::span`.

Comment: A [wrapper](https://godbolt.org/g/7JId3W) is simple to write.

Comment: [std::mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should do what you want.

Comment: What kind of processing do you want to do? You already have a pointer, just treat it as if it were an array, and let the compiler do the rest of the work for you. What more do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `view::counted(ptr, length)` to make a range of `length` elements starting at `ptr`.